# How to run k6 tests on amazon cloud

Tags: javascript, testing, cloud, amazon-ecs, k6

I want to run some load tests but my pc cannot handle more requests than the server. So I would like to run these tests on amazon ecs. Is there a way to run k6 on amazon cloud instead of their loadimpact cloud, if so, how?

Comment: What kind of tests are you running that you are not able to run from your machine. Not that kind of test are not possible (they are very easily) , just maybe you don't need to be running this big of a tests ;). 

As a general answer: the same way you will run anything else in aws :) There is no specific things, because k6 is in golang it is actually somewhat easier to deploy as it has practically 1 dependencies  - glibc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run k6 on Amazon cloud. The easiest way is probably to stand up a Centos or Ubuntu server in ec2 and then install k6 on it. This is how I have run it. Then install InfluxDB on the server also along with Grafana. Feed the output of the load test from k6 into InfluxDB and there is a community Grafana dashboard that will display stats from the load test. It will be close to using LoadImpact. You will still need to use LoadImpact to create the scripts if you are using the web browser plugin. But that is free.

You can run k6 inside a docker container too. I have not done that yet, but a coworker did. I am going to look into using ECS to run the container version of k6. But I have not tried it yet. You would still want an ec2 instance with InfluxDB to grab the data out of k6.